# Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object (and) Undefined index: listing_type

Tags: php, indexing, undefined

> Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object (and) Undefined index: listing_type

```
if (!file_exists($upload['basedir'].'/ulisting/css/'.$args['listing_type']->ID.'/'.$css_file_name.".css")) {
    $style_url = $upload['baseurl']."/ulisting/css/".$css_file_name.".css";
} else {
    $style_url = $upload['baseurl'].'/ulisting/css/'.$args['listing_type']->ID.'/'.$css_file_name.".css";
}
```

Comment: `$args` is probably not defined, and since you've got no code showing us how you set the `$args` value we can't possibly know or properly help you. Please read [SO | How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `$args` does not have index `listing_type`, that's why you get `$args['listing_type']->ID // Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: I guess $args is defined but empty or not containing what you are looking for, if you used `func_get_arg ` be aware that the key is the index 0,1,2... not the name of the arg

Answer (score 0):

Try to verify what is actually in $args. Make some simple dump above your lines of code

```
    var_dump($args);die;
if (!file_exists($upload['basedir'].'/ulisting/css/'.$args['listing_type']->ID.'/'.$css_file_name.".css")) {
    $style_url = $upload['baseurl']."/ulisting/css/".$css_file_name.".css";
} else {
    $style_url = $upload['baseurl'].'/ulisting/css/'.$args['listing_type']->ID.'/'.$css_file_name.".css";
}
```

Comment: I tried with this code but If I apply page goes to blank white.

Comment: could be layout issue and dump result is hidden, you can try pres ctr+u to see actual code or inspect (F12) to view html
if no you can try this line  instead
 `return print_r($args, true);`
should help if that render actually is expected to display any content on page

Answer (score 0):

Not solved the full function is

```php
public static function render($sections, $css_file_name, $args) {
    $content = "";
    $upload = wp_get_upload_dir();

    if (!file_exists($upload['basedir'].'/ulisting/css/'.$args['listing_type']->ID.'/'.$css_file_name.".css")) 
    {
        $style_url = $upload['baseurl']."/ulisting/css/".$css_file_name.".css";
    } else {
        $style_url = $upload['baseurl'].'/ulisting/css/'.$args['listing_type']->ID.'/'.$css_file_name.".css";
    }
    wp_enqueue_style('ulisting_builder_stytle_'.$css_file_name, $style_url);

    if(is_array($sections) AND !empty($sections)) {
        foreach ($sections as $section) {
            $content .= StmListingTemplate::load_template('builder/section',['section' => $section, 'args' => $args]);
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```php
if (!file_exists($upload['basedir'].'/ulisting/css/'.$args['listingType']->ID.'/'.$css_file_name.".css")) {
    $style_url = $upload['baseurl']."/ulisting/css/".$css_file_name.".css";
} else {
    $style_url = $upload['baseurl'].'/ulisting/css/'.$args['listingType']->ID.'/'.$css_file_name.".css";
}
wp_enqueue_style('ulisting_builder_stytle_'.$css_file_name, $style_url);
```